# Why was the sponsors logo was missing?

Tags: cricket, tournaments, uniform

On 27 February 2014, while watching the Asia cup match between India VS Bangladesh I noticed a that the shirts worn by Indian team players didn't have a sponsors logo on the chest portion, even though they had logos on their arms.

Can anyone give me the reason why the sponsors logo was missing on the chest of an Indian player's shirt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logo is missing due to the contract between Star India and BCCI. According to that contract, the star India logo will only be shown on the arms of the jersey for Asia cup.

> "We have different sets of agreements for different tournaments with
>   the BCCI. Not wearing the logo on chest was according to our pact for
>   the tournament and the rules of Asia Cup. You might see a different
>   jersey for the World Twenty20 next month," Nitin Kukreja, a top honcho
>   of Star India, said.
>   - [Source](http://www.bangaloremirror.com/sports/cricket/Curious-case-of-missing-star-logo-at-Asia-Cup/articleshow/31058153.cms).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I having doubt that is you have mentioned about the rules of asia cup which menas no team should have the logo on there chest but we have seen Bangladesh were having Sahara Logo on there shirt (on chest).So can you please elaborate on that

Comment: @shaan, contract is between India's cricket board and Star India for Asia Cup.

Comment: @ Sports Fan but you have mentioned rules of a Asia cup in your answer

Comment: @shaan, `rules of Asia cup` is mentioned by Star India Official. But the CEO of Asian cricket council said that there is no rules to prevent logos on jersey. It is up to the team. You can see the other teams having the logo.